# Create a table of empty ("") values from a data.frame in r

Tags: r, count, na

I have some code I wrote to create a table of column names and the count of how many values within each column are `NA`. Now I would like to change this code to count how many empty strings `""` are present in the columns.

Here is some generic data:

```
d <- data.frame("ID" = c("A", "B", "", "C"),
                "VAL" = c(1, NA, 2, 3),
                "ORDER" = c(0, 3, 6, 7),
                "MARKET" = c("ENT", "HOUSE", "RETAIL", ""))
```

And here is my code that generates a table of how many `NA` are present in the columns.
**Note:** *It only puts columns in the table that contain at least 1 `NA` and this **is** intentional. This is because there are a lot of columns in the data and I want the table to only reflect the columns with missing values - the ones I care about.*

Code:

```
c_names <- names(d)
k <- 0
cont_NA <- NA
for (i in 1:(dim(d)[2])) {
  z <- unique(is.na(d[, i]))

  if(length(z) == 2){

    if(!is.na(cont_NA)){
      cont_NA <- c(cont_NA, c_names[i])
    }else{
      cont_NA <- c_names[i]
    }
  }
}
rm(i, k, z)

missing <- data.frame("Column" = NA,
                      "Missing_Values" = NA)
for(p in 1:length(cont_NA)){
  s <- sum(is.na(d[, c_names %in% cont_NA[p]]))

  missing[p, 1] <- cont_NA[p]
  missing[p, 2] <- s
}
rm(p, s, cont_NA)
missing
```

My question is how do I convert this code to do the same thing except to count `""` instead? In the above code I am using the function `is.na` but I am unaware of a function to count empty strings.

Sample Output from the above code is:

```
Column  Missing_Values
   VAL               1
```

Sample Output to my problem would look like this:

```
Column  Missing_Values
    ID               1
MARKET               1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` & `tidyr` solution. First, I create the data frame.

```
d <- data.frame("ID" = c("A", "B", "", "C"),
                "VAL" = c(1, NA, 2, 3),
                "ORDER" = c(0, 3, 6, 7),
                "MARKET" = c("ENT", "HOUSE", "RETAIL", ""))
```

Then, I check for empty strings and sum all instances. I `gather` all the columns from wide to long format, and filter out those with zero empty strings.

```
d %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(sum(. == "", na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  gather(Column, Missing_Values) %>% 
  filter(Missing_Values > 0)
```

which gives,

```
#   Column Missing_Values
# 1     ID              1
# 2 MARKET              1
```

Comment: Loading `library(dplyr)` did not work because it could not find the function `gather` since it is in `tidyr` so your solution works after loading in the whole `library(tidyverse)` package.

Comment: @Bear Ack. You're right. I'll update my answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use for loops. Look into the "apply" function. It will make your life a whole lot easier.

```
# Sum up empty string per column over all columns using the apply function
tmp <- apply(d,2,function(x) sum(x=='',na.rm=TRUE)) 

# Create new dataframe of the results
res <- data.frame('Column'=names(tmp), 'Missing_Values'=as.numeric(tmp)) 

# Display results with nonzero values
res[res$Missing_Values!=0,]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
n <- colSums(d == "", na.rm = TRUE)
rev(stack(n[n > 0]))
#      ind values
# 1     ID      1
# 2 MARKET      1
```

Comment: I like this answer more than mine because it is more concise, uses the `colSums` function directly instead of using `apply(sum)`, and also reveals two base functions I have never heard of / used: `rev` and `stack`. Thanks!